# How to refresh a table after ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

My problem is that i don't need to refresh who will refresh a table content, i need to do this with jQuery, on client side.Is this possible?

I have a table which will contains the information recieved from database. In this table i have a button, at whose pressing it will be sent AJAX request to function, which will ban the comment. It will be perfect if content of the table will change after succes AJAX response (desirable row containing  with status)

```html
<table class="table">
  <!-- Here is my table -->
  <?php foreach ($comments as $row) { ?>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php echo $row->Content; ?>
    </td>
    <td>                                            <!--------- /// --------->
      <?php if ($row->IsBanned == 0): ?>            <!--------- /// --------->
      <span class="label label-success ls">OK</span><!------ THIS  ROW ------>
      <?php else: ?>                                <!------ will  be  ------>
      <span class="label label-danger ls">Ban</span><!------ refreshed ------>
      <?php endif ?>                                <!--------- /// --------->
    </td>                                           <!--------- /// --------->
    <td style="text-align: right;">
      <div class="t_a_r" style="display: inline-flex;">
        <?php if ($row->IsBanned == 0): ?>
        <a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs ban" id="<?php echo $row->IdComment; ?>" role="button"><i class="margin-0 fa fa-ban"></i></a> <!-- on click this button to send ajax -->
        <?php endif ?>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php } ?>
</table>
```

and on click button $(".ban") i send an ajax request to codeigniter function. Script:

```js
$('.ban').click(function(event) {
      var id = $(this).attr('id');
    
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: {
          id: id
        },
        cache: false,
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>admin/banQuestion',
        success: function(msg) {
          //here code to refresh table content
          //for example table column which contains "Status"
        },
      });
    });
```

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: @Heri, I have edited the question. now it's clearer? Some ideas how to do it?

Comment: @DanPlaton what you can do is give your column and specific id lets say status_<id of record> and on success callback you can use the that id to update the content of that column with $("#status_"+id).html("new status");

Comment: @Tarun, yes it's a good idea. Thanks ;)